# Create Activation Context Failes

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, side-by-side, activation-context-api

I try to put my VS 2012 .Net Project together with an old native Dll built with VS 2005     in one directory. For installation reason, I can not install the VC Redists on the users machine, therefore I put msvcr, msvcp, msvcm and vcomp Dll in the newest redist version I've found from MS also in that directory. I've created to .Manifest files Microsoft.VC80.CRT.Manifest and Microsoft.VC80.OpenMP.Manifest files with this content, e.g. for CRT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Copyright © 1981-2001 Microsoft Corporation-->
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" type="win32" processorArchitecture="amd64" version="8.0.50608.0"/>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" processorArchitecture="amd64" version="8.0.50727.6195" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.0.41204.256-8.0.50727.762" newVersion="8.0.50727.6195"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
<file name="msvcr80.dll"/>
<file name="msvcp80.dll"/>
<file name="msvcm80.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

From analysing the event log and sxstrace I've seen he is looking for version 8.0.50608.0 and I offer and redirect to 8.0.50727.6195.

As I said, in eventvwr and sxstrace I saw some failure and fixed them. Now in eventlog nothing appears, but sxstrace says only: Creation of activation context failed. Without any reason why. From the application itself, I get the Side-by-side configuration error message box.

The whole stuff is 64 bit. The .Net application, the wrapper and the native Dll.

If I install the redist package, it works fine. But for my target machines, that is not possible.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: You can search the machine with installed redist for "8.0.50608.0" (or whatevr works), and grab the .dll-s and the .manifest-s (which should be renamed appropriately) from there.